# React.js not finding main route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my route file. For some reason the routing stopped to work while I was updating a component. Now I'm getting the error below to my main page:

> ```
> Cannot GET /
> ```

Route file:

```
/* ERROR PAGES */
var notfound = require('./routes/notfound.jsx');

/* APP PAGES */
var charts = require('./routes/app/charts.jsx');

/* ROUTES */
module.exports = (
  <Route handler={ReactRouter.RouteHandler}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={charts} />
    <Route path='/' handler={charts} />
    <NotFoundRoute handler={notfound} />
  </Route>
);
```

There is no error on the console. Just the message "Cannot GET /" and a 404 code.

I'm using React-Router.

Comment: `Cannot GET /` seems like a server-side issue to me (specifically Express). Are you doing server rendering with `React.renderToString` and React Router?

Comment: @BinaryMuse I'm using React Router. There is a integration with a ExpressJS API but it's not the problem once the API works correctly when called  and this error "Cannot GET /" appears before any call to the API.

I can't even render my index page.

Comment: I mean that React Router can't generate status codes on the client. Your browser requests a page, which returns HTML/JS, and *then* React and React Router take over and perform client-side routing. If you're getting a 404, then your client-side code isn't even running. We'll probably need some more details—when exactly do you get the error, is there anything on the console, what are you using to serve the app, etc.

Comment: I have the same error for every path but '/'. There is nothing on the console, just a plain "Cannot GET /...". Even based on the example given in the docs (Overview) with the App, Inbox and About. "App" is displayed at root '/', but '/inbox' or '/about' are broken. Is it a question of configuring Apache to allow these ?